# Obtaining Image Measurements of a Known Object

Tags: computational-geometry, image-processing, computer-vision

Given the image of an adhesive tape as below, what would be possible method to find the tape radius?

The image sepia toned with artificial background added. The tape itself is partially hidden.

[image: Sepia toned picture of adhesive tape]

Comment: Of course we can help you, with ideas behind the task. This is not programming site, moreover it is in the form of Q&A, so what is your question? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? What resources have you exhausted so far? What techniques discarded, and why?

Answer (score 1):

*I think you're looking for a way to approach this problem  however I am not sure if the question belongs to this site(Seems more relavant to https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ and  https://stackoverflow.com)*

A typical approach will be ***canny edge detection , finding Contours*** and then ***Elliptical Curve Fitting***.Then you can find the approximate diameter and divide it by two.

Below are some links that will help you

Documentation from **OpenCV** (*an open source library for image processing*) library will shed a light on finding contours

http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

How to find contours in an image using c++ and OpenCV

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html

See the following for getting an idea about curve fitting

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting

How to implement Elliptical Curve fitting using c++ and OpenCV

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html

Answer (score 0):

The Hough transform for circles would be appropriate here. It will yield radius as output and thanks to tape being a ring (with some bigger radius) will help, more results with the same center will appear. In fact it will work even with partially visible objects. If you can supply estimated size then runtime can be drastically decreased. But in that case the RANSAC for circles might be even better.

The core problem here is not the circle detection (and measurement) but the image tone. The standard edge detectors yield poor results (I have tested Canny, Roberts, Sobel and Laplacian). The sepia tone is a bit tricky part, but may be ignored. Second tricky part is the second circle in the image. Although the Hough transform gives far greater response for the tape, such situation should be included into pipeline of transforms. In this particular case the shadow removal would suffice (naive thresholding would work). It means that we treat the darkest parts of the image as shadow / background (this comes from very common idea that interesting object should be centered and see some light).